# NPM Installations messing up

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, titanium, npm

I am trying to get Titanium Studio to work for some time now..  I am using Linux Mint XFCE Edition.

I have to install nodejs and the packages titanium, alloy, acs, acs-node with npm.

Now every time I install nodejs again and install a titanium or alloy via npm it creates a new directory `/[sudo] password for username: /home/ioan/[sudo] password for username: /usr/lib/node_modules`
I actually have a directory called `[sudo] password for username:` in my root dir (where username is my username).

All the other pacakages I need to install (acs, acs-node) give me:

```
> ws@0.4.31 install /[sudo] password for username: /home/ioan/[sudo] password for username: /usr/lib/node_modules/acs/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

I really hope, someone can help me! I don't understand at all what is going on. I am installing nodejs from PPA: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/ because the version from the Linux Mint repository are way to old.

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried 'npm install titanium alloy acs acs-node'?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the same exact problem.

Comment: @kisplit No, the only way was to build node.js from core. I had no luck with the packages from the repository

Comment: I also had this problem. I think it's something to do with titanium, I tried to uninstall all node packages and reinstall, same error

/home/joseph/[sudo] password for joseph: /home/joseph/apps/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for joseph: /home/joseph/apps/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for joseph: /home/joseph/apps/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for joseph: /home/joseph/apps/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for joseph: /home/joseph/apps/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for joseph: /home/joseph/apps/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for joseph: /home/joseph/